# Rsync --bwlimit not working

Tags: linux, rsync

I am currently using rsync to transfert large file from a host to another.
I would like to limit the debit for this transfert. After reading the man page I found the option --bwlimit which is expecting a KB/s value.

I want to limit the transfert to arround 100Mbit/s
So I used the following settings :

```
rsync --progress -v --bwlimit=10000 --temp-dir=/tmp srv:/tmp/* /tmp/
```

But this doesn't seems to be respected according to the output of rsync :

```
file.sql.gz
   570851702 100%   33.90MB/s    0:00:16 (xfer#5, to-check=34/39)
file.sql.gz
    11195140 100%    7.45MB/s    0:00:01 (xfer#6, to-check=33/39)
file.sql.gz
    51439169 100%   19.41MB/s    0:00:02 (xfer#7, to-check=32/39)
file.sql.gz
       34022 100%    1.55MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#8, to-check=31/39)
file.sql.gz
     2305698 100%    6.96MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#9, to-check=30/39)
file.sql.gz
     2152942 100%    2.73MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#10, to-check=29/39)
file.sql.gz
    86655633 100%   19.33MB/s    0:00:04 (xfer#11, to-check=28/39)
file.sql.gz
  3614476032  40%   34.82MB/s    0:02:28
```

If I'm not wrong : 19.33MB/s ~= 154Mbit/s

So what is wrong here ?

PS : rsync  version 3.0.6  protocol version 30

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Here it works with rsync 3.0.4 (Ubuntu), 3.0.6 (openSUSE) and 3.0.9 (Ubuntu) using the same parameters. You have to provide more information about your system.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064316/rsync-limit-transfer-speed-not-working

Comment: @mreithub The answer in this post is indeed interesting but actually Hugo seems to transfer rather large files.

Comment: rsync bwlimits for each file, to limit bw   you should limit connection , (on linux using iptables+tc http://atmail.com/kb/2009/throttling-bandwidth/), so no easy way.

Comment: Hello,  I am running RHEL 6 but this doesn't make much difference. Yes this is large file, so debit should be almost stable. For information the equivalent command with SCP is working great. So I don't know what is wrong with rsync.

Comment: You could compile and try a vanilla rsync. Maybe some redhat patches broke the bwlimit function of your rsync although I doubt that.

Comment: Have you tried to measure the overall time and then figure out what's KB/S?

Comment: It does not function everytime, but I had better luck with `trickle` --- see http://www.tuxradar.com/content/control-your-bandwidth-trickle

Answer (score 16):

I think you experienced some "burstiness" as mentioned in the manpage:

```
--bwlimit=RATE
          ... 
          Some "burstiness" may be seen where rsync writes out a block 
          of data and then sleeps to bring the average rate into compliance.
```

So as I asked before the overall ratio at the end of your job was at last limited to 10M.

Comment: "burstiness" might be the best thing I've heard in a long time.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in [rsync man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), it transfer in KByte/sec:

```
--bwlimit=KBPS          limit I/O bandwidth; KBytes per second
```

Comment: That's what I used : 10 000 kilobytes = 78.12500 megabits

Comment: You didn't pay attention to what i said. The rsync use _Byte_ instead of _bit_, so you have to calculate the bandwidth in **bit** and covert it to **byte**

Comment: I have the same issues, when i put `--bwlimit=100`, i obtain 275kB/s, very regular between 265-285 kB/s,  no burstiness. What is wrong in here?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to limit the transfer to arround 100Mbit/s So I used the following settings:
>
> ```
> rsync --progress -v --bwlimit=10000 --temp-dir=/tmp srv:/tmp/* /tmp/
> ```

100 Mbit/s is (approximately) 10 MByte/s, which is indeed 10,000 KByte/s. If you're hitting `rsync` burstiness then maybe the separate tool `trickle` will help:

```
trickle -s -d 10000 -u 10000 -t 10 -l 100 rsync --progress -v --temp-dir=/tmp srv:/tmp/* /tmp/
```

Answer (score 1):

The value shown is the effective transfer rate which includes speeds up from compression and the delta algorithm, this can be easily observed by seeing large numbers if an interrupted `rsync` session is restarted with partial transfers enabled (ex `--append-verify`).